# Reverse direction of Kendo UI Linear Gauge

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Using a Kendo UI Datawiz component (Linear gauge) in my project. It's supposed to be an indicator for depth, where surface is at 0 (top) and bottom should be at x (bottom). Currently I have not figured out how to 'reverse' the direction of the gauge, causing it to start at 0, and move downwards towards x at bottom.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Here's my gauge:

```
        function createGauges() {
            var value = $("#depthBar").val();

            $("#depthBar").kendoLinearGauge({
                pointer: {
                    value: 28,
                    shape: "arrow"
                },

                scale: {
                    majorUnit: 20,
                    minorUnit: 2,
                    min: -40,
                    max: 60,
                    vertical: true,
                    directions: 


                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            createGauges();
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aaand, I've found the answer. Actually missed a tiny piece of code in the docs;

```
...
    scale: {
        majorUnit: 1000,
        minorUnit: 500,
        min: 0,
        max: 12000,
        vertical: true,
        reverse: true
    }
...
```